# What terms are used for a non-native speaker of Japanese?

Tags: meaning, words

What terms are used for a non-native speaker of a language? I found ネイティブスピーカー and 母語話者 but I want to know the Japanese words for a non-native speaker. Thanks.

Comment: The [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AC%AC%E4%BA%8C%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E) uses 第二言語話者 to mean literally 'a speaker of a second language'. I'm not sure however if this is commonly used.

Comment: I needed to take French as a second language:「第二外国語」at University. Mais, Je ne parle pas Francais...

Comment: English normally has been in school curriculum until high school. 英語 should be 第一外国語 for many Japanese. Since I was not taught English until Junior-High, I guess my first encounter to foreign language was 中国語 used in the movie of [酔拳: Drunken Master](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC_%E9%85%94%E6%8B%B3) by Jackie Chen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply, you can use 非【ひ】ネイティブ or 非ネイティブスピーカー.

Comment: that answer is too simple :)

Comment: @JACK But this is the answer to your simple question "what's the term for nonnative speaker?" :)

Comment: almost sounds like hinative maybe a word pun.

Comment: @JACK What kind of pun? Is this the first time you saw 非 ("non-")?

Comment: 非常口 is a term that i know

Comment: @JACK are you pronouncing the website hinative like 非ネイティブ?

Comment: yes i am ha hi hu he ho.

Comment: @JACK They're not the same... Hinative is just like... "Hi, native". That would sound like ハイネイティブ, not ひネイティブ.

Comment: i just go with the spelling! :)

Comment: Ah, a pun on HiNative.com and 非ネイティブ! :D

Answer (score -2):

I would call a non-native speaker of Japanese [非日本語話者]{ひにほんごわしゃ}, though it might sound a little bit academic.

Comment: Uh, that’d be “non-Japanese speaker”. Did you mean 日本語非母語話者？ (Not that I’d recommend that either given that it’s a mouthful)

Comment: No, I didn't mean 日本語非母語話者. Although I googled and found 日本語非母語話者, it is awkward and mouthful as you say. I don't think 非日本語話者 is mouthful. Strictly speaking, non-Japanese speaker and non-native Japanese speaker might be different but could mean the same depending on the context.

Comment: A non-native speaker of Japanese is usually someone who can speak Japanese. They just aren't native. I wouldn't introduce myself as a non-native speaker of German, for instance, because I speak no German.

Comment: Thanks Leebo. Now, I've got it.